# rebinding ESC in insert mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

In `Evil`, The default binding of `ESC` in insert mode is `(evil-normal-state nil)`.

I want to rebind ESC in insert mode like this:

`(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "ESC") 
                      (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello")))`

However, when I try to do this I get unexpected behavior. First, the binding does not change. And for a reason I don't understand it also breaks `M-x` in insert mode.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely related to the fact that `ESC` is an ASCII character which is used in all kinds of "escape sequences" and which Emacs normally considers as an alternative to the `Meta` modifier.

IIRC Evil handles this issue by mapping the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key not to the `ESC` character (code 27), as done by default in Emacs, but to the `escape` event.  So you might like to try:

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map [escape]
            (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello")))
```